# ng-if not working properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I call `console.log($scope.showAddEvent)` it shows that `showAddEvent` is changing but the ng-if doesn't seem to be reflecting those changes. It doesn't show it at all.

I'm still pretty new to angularjs so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

**html**

```
  <ion-footer-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive" ng-if="$scope.showAddEvent == true">
      <div class="title" ng-click="modal.show()">Add Event</div>
  </ion-footer-bar>
```

**controller.js**

```
  $scope.showAddEvent;

  var currentUser = Backand.getUserDetails().$$state.value;
  if (currentUser.role == "Admin" || currentUser.role == "Verified"){
      $scope.showAddEvent = true;
      console.log(currentUser.role);
      console.log('you can add event');
      console.log($scope.showAddEvent);
  }
  else {
      $scope.showAddEvent = false;
      console.log(currentUser.role);
      console.log('You cannot add Event');
    console.log($scope.showAddEvent);
  }
```

Comment: You don't need `$scope` in the html template it should be `ng-if="showAddEvent"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template, you shouldn't reference scope.  Change

```
<ion-footer-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive" ng-if="$scope.showAddEvent == true">
```

to

```
<ion-footer-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive" ng-if="showAddEvent">
```

Comment: As a small update you can do `ng-if="showAddEvent"` if `$scope.showAddEvent` is always going to be of type `boolean`. This just makes things slightly neater, in my opinion.

Comment: Indeed.  I cringe a little every time I see an equality comparison with a boolean literal

Comment: @DustinHodges I know what you mean, but it depends on context. Sometimes I like to make it clear, being how ambiguous JS is at times...

Taylor be forewarned, you will run into lots of little things like this with Angular. Good luck!